# Is there a cost for gcp cloud functions to access gcp storage buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Trying to figure out some gcp storage costs.

I have several applications running in GCP cloud functions, some of which store while others pull data from gcp storage buckets in the same region.

I want to know if there are any costs associated in cloud functions pulling or accessing data stored in gcp storage buckets ? Would that classify as egress cost and charged at $0.08/GB.

Additionally, if I end up configuring Google private access for cloud storage, will there again be any cost associated in my cloud functions pulling data from gcp cloud storage if I’m traversing over googles own backbone infrastructure ?

Comment: Have you read https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing?

Comment: Thanks for the link @FerreginaPelona. It clarifies the difference between retrieval + operational fees to network egress. 

It does look like if cloud services like cloud functions access data from gcp buckets in the same region, there isn’t any network egress cost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per @FerreginaPelona's comment on [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing), it clarifies the difference between retrieval + operational fees to network egress. If data is accessed in the same region, there aren't any network egress costs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question. Just to add one point here if you want to know rough estimate from cost prospective then google calculator is a good option . You can provide your details about GCP services you want to use and it can give you the estimated cost based on GCP services.